# Cursor.moveToNext() loop occasionally gets stuck

Tags: android, android-cursor

I'm running a standard contact query to get device contacts via:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    // code
}
```

I'm measuring the progress with a horizontal progress bar by initially setting `progressBar.setMax(cursor.getCount());` and in the while loop doing `progressBar.setProgress(++i)`. Once the loop is complete, I load the contacts.

Very rarely, the bar will stop filling at some spot and the contacts will never load. I'm assuming the cursor is getting stuck at some contact. No crash, no 'app is not responding' message.

Note: This is on certain person's devices and stuck at the exact same spot. I haven't been able to reproduce it. That's why it's most likely contact specific.

My questions are:

What is the possible cause of this?
If it is a specific contact, is there a way to skip it and keep the loop going? If not, break the loop and load the contacts up to that point.

I need the first name, last name, phone, email, and photo

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            progressBar.setProgress(++i);

            if(this.isCancelled()){
                break;
            }

            String name = cursor.getString(nameColumn);
            String firstName = "";
            String lastName = "";

            if(name != null) {
                int spaceIndex = name.indexOf(" ");
                firstName = name;
                lastName = "";
                if (spaceIndex != -1) {
                    firstName = name.substring(0, spaceIndex);
                    lastName = name.substring(spaceIndex + 1);
                }
            }

            String email = cursor.getString(emailColumn);
            String id = cursor.getString(idColumn);

            String mobile = null, home = null, work = null, other = null;
            Cursor phonesCursor = null;


                try {
               // Need a separate query to get the phone number
                    phonesCursor = contentResolver.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            phoneProjection, phoneSelection, new String[]{id}, null);

                    while (phonesCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        int type = phonesCursor.getInt(phonesCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                        String phone = phonesCursor.getString(phonesCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        switch (type) {
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                                mobile = phone;
                                break;
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                                home = phone;
                                break;
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                                work = phone;
                                break;
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_OTHER:
                                other = phone;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally {
                    if(phonesCursor != null)
                        phonesCursor.close();
                }


            String photoUrl = null;
            if (getPhoto){
                photoUrl = cursor.getString(photoColumn);
            }

            // Code here to set the name, email, to my object
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i would surround the block with a try catch, also write something to the logcat which shows you which contact is hanging..

Comment: and what is the error you are being displayed?

Comment: @JohanV i can't reproduce it. it breaks for some people, the only way would be to get their device and that's not possible. the error is the progress bar getting stuck at some spot and never finishing the loop

Comment: if you cant reproduce the error at will, its a bit hard...you must try to reproduce the error at will..i would myself if the code works well on every device i try..i def try to get hands on the same device the error is being produced..i wont drink coffee until i get one

Comment: given what i have, is it possible to skip over that contact? have some sort of timer and if it takes too long just go to the next one? not sure if that is implementable

Comment: I prefer trying to catch the exception..u can send it to ur server if u dont know the user

Comment: More code please! The question is too general and we have thousands of possible bugs.

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung code added!

Comment: What do you mean by "never finishing the loop" in the previous answer? Did it get out of the block or just about the progress bar to stop at some point?

Comment: The progress bar just stops. I'm assuming it gets stuck on a contact.